# C# clr udf for Active Directory group membership

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, active-directory, sqlclr, udf

My problem is as follows: I need a clr udf (in C#) to query with a given ad-usr the ad-group membership

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlInt32 check_user_is_part_of_ad_grp(SqlString ad_usr, SqlString ad_grp)
    {
        bool bMemberOf = false;

        // set up domain context
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        // find the group in question
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, ad_grp.ToString());
        UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, ad_usr.ToString());

        if (group != null && usr != null)
        {
            bMemberOf = usr.IsMemberOf(group);
        }

        // Put your code here
        return new SqlInt32 (bMemberOf ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

If I publish the CLR to my SQL Server 2008 (.net 3.5), then I run the udf as follows:

```
select dbo.check_user_is_part_of_ad_grp('user', 'group')
```

And I get an error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "check_user_is_part_of_ad_grp":
>   System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesPermission, System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed.
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   at UserDefinedFunctions.check_user_is_part_of_ad_grp(SqlString ad_usr, SqlString ad_grp)

I set the target framework of my project to 3.5 and the permission level to `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. Also the project references (`System.DirectoryServices`,  `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManamgement`, `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`) to `EXTERNAL`

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Most likely all of those Assemblies will need to be set to `UNSAFE`, especially the three **System.DirectoryServices*** .NET Framework libraries that you imported. Also, since you are importing [unsupported .NET Framework libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx), you will need to set the database to `TRUSTWORTHY ON` in order to get them to work. Setting a Database to `TRUSTWORTHY ON` is typically something you want to avoid as it is a security risk, but in this case I do not believe that it can be avoided.

That said, I am not sure that you even need to create this function yourself in SQLCLR. If you are just wanting to know if a Login (Windows Logins only, obviously) belongs to a particular Active Directory group, there is a built-in function that *should* do that for you. The [IS_MEMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186271.aspx) function will indicate if the *current* Login is a member of the specified Windows group (specified as `Domain\Group`). The difference in how this function works as opposed to the one that you are creating is that it only works for the current Login; you cannot pass any arbitrary Login into it. BUT, it also doesn't require any of the extra effort and security risks that are a part of *this* SQLCLR solution. So, something to consider :-).

Comment from O.P. on this answer:

> Actually, I need to check an arbitrary Login if it's member of a particular group. I even tried to use a stored proc and `OPENQUERY' with a linked server to ADSI, but this only works as Dynamic SQL since I need to inject group and user.

In that case, just make the Dynamic SQL two layers deep instead of the usual one layer. Something along the lines of:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'
  SELECT *
  FROM   OPENQUERY([LinkedServer], N''
             SELECT *
             FROM   someResource
             WHERE  GroupName=N''''' + @Group + N'''''
             AND    ObjectName=N''''' + @Login + N''''';
                   '');
';

PRINT @SQL; -- DEBUG
EXEC (@SQL);
```

In this approach, the query executing `OPENQUERY` is Dynamic SQL, but the query given to `OPENQUERY` to execute is a string literal.

Comment: actually i need to check an arbitrary Login if its member of an particular group. i even tried to use a stored-proc an openquery with an linked server to ADSI but this only works as dynamic sql since i need to inject group and user, as we're having a huge ad with many groups and users.

Comment: Does the Linked Server to ADSI work at all? You can get around the Dynamic SQL limitation of `OPENQUERY` by creating the Dynamic SQL to include the entire OPENQUERY call and then EXEC that.

Comment: i didnt get it.. how did you mean i can get arround the dyn-sql limitation? you have an example?

Comment: if i do it like this i'll get an Error Msg 443, Invalid use ofd a side-affecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a function

Comment: @rudash04 Correct, this cannot be done in a Function. It needs to be housed in a stored procedure. If you have a list, then you need to use a cursor to iterate over the list and call the stored procedure for each value.